# DoesNotExist at /home/ Friend matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

```
from home.models import Post,Friend
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name='home/home.html'

    def get(self,request):
        form=HomeForm()
        posts=Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        users=User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)

        friend=Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
        friends=friend.users.all()
```

Comment: show your complete error traceback

Comment: What is confusing you about this error? You don't have a Friend for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

> Friend matching query does not exist

This error is because your query is empty. `.get()` will return an error if the query is either empty or contain more than one result. Use `.filter()` instead with proper conditions.

See this [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) of the doc.

When `.get()` returns an object directly, `filter()` returns a queryset so you have to check if the queryset is empty and then use `queryset.first()` or `queryset[0]`.

Another solution is to wrap your `.get()` in a try/except block:

```
try:
    friend=Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
except:
    # No Friend was found for this current_user
    # Do something
```

Comment: AttributeError at /home/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'users' occuring on using filter()